# ASP.NET LINE ITEMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner to ASP.NET MVC 5. I am trying to create an inventoory management system, in which we can give orders , purchase items e.t.c. I want to design a system in which we can select items to buy,their quantity and price. I have an idea that i can do this in table, but i dont know how to increase the table rows dynamically, everytime i click a button to add new item, so that with every click a new row is produced in which i can select a new item.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic table rows are not something that is built into ASP.NET MVC. I suggest using a front-end library for data binding, and [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) is great for that.

Check out the *Observable Arrays* and *the foreach binding* part, they are exactly what you need.

Basically you need to declare the array in javascript, use `data-bind="foreach: myArray"` in your `<tbody>` HTML and then add a JS function that performs `myArray.push(newValue);`

Comment: Actually all of this is too much to be understand by me,i am at a beginner level yet. i saw knockout but it's really hard, is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain client side listing using javascript or jquery. 
Make dynamically table when user click button add row in table.

You can also use third party js library like datatable , jqgrid etc. You can explore it.

Datatable
https://datatables.net/

Jqgrid
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html